# Contour complex integration with specifications

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

i already ask that one, but i am now confused, i been trying using series for the first and second one but i really don´t know how to continue so i need help and a rigorous, formal and step by step answer. Like always i really appreciate your help.

$$\int_\gamma e^{\dfrac{1}{z^2}}dz$$
$$\int_\gamma e^{\dfrac{1}{z}}dz$$

where $$\gamma:|z|=1 $$
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{d\theta}{1+sin^2(\theta)}$$
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $e^x$ has the Maclaurin series
$$1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$$
if we make the substitution $x\mapsto \frac{1}{z^2}$ then we get the Laurent series
$$e^\frac{1}{z^2} = 1 + \frac{1}{z^2} + \frac{1}{2!\,z^4} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{z^6}\right)$$
The residue for the above series is the coefficient of the term $\frac{1}{z}$. That term does not appear in the Laurent series, so it is simply $0$.

If we instead make the substitution $x\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ then we have the Laurent series
$$e^\frac{1}{z} = 1 + \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2!\,z^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{z^3}\right)$$
the residue in this case is then $1$.